# The class CFL\cap co-CFL

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, context-free

Is anything nontrivial known about the class $\mathrm{CFL}\cap \mathrm{coCFL}$? <del>In particular, is it known whether $\mathrm{CFL}\cap \mathrm{coCFL} = \mathrm{DCFL}$ (certainly the reverse containment is obvious.)? I hope I'm not being stupid here--don't laugh at me too much if this is totally trivial.</del> I ask this because I'm trying to pin down a commutative closure of a regular language over a binary alphabet, and it's clear that it lies inside this set, via a result showing that slip-languages over an alphabet of size two have context-free commutative closure.

Comment: [A related question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89142).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For every finite, non-unary alphabet, the language of all palindromes is not in DCFL, but in the intersection of coCFL and CFL.

Comment: Yep--you're absolutely right. Sorry about that! Let me change the question to reflect this.

Comment: isn't the question answered at this point ?

Comment: Indeed--I was hoping for some characterization of the class, but since I really originally asked whether it was DCFL, it's only fair to accept!